# How to play youtube video with default html5 controls?

Tags: javascript

I'm so sorry, but I can't get a youtube video to play (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyRv0-oPfKE) inside a video tag.
I know about the iframe API but in this case it has to have the default html5 controls, not the youtube controls. 
I probably missed something stupid but can't figure it out...

Anyone know how to do this?

EDIT:

so I tried:

```
<video
          controls='controls' 

          src={`http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=${id}&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US`}
          type='video/mp4'
        />
```

and tried:

```
<video
  controls='controls' 

  src={`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyRv0-oPfKE&html5=1`}
  type='video/mp4'
/>
```

but I get blank page.

Answer (score 0):

The [HTML `video` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) expects video files as a source. If you want to play a YouTube video using the native HTML video player, you'll have to provide [a link to the video itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566835/how-to-get-the-mp4-url-for-youtube-videos-using-youtube-v3-api), not to the YouTube website for this video.

Also keep in mind, that not all browsers can handle any video formats. See [MDN: Media formats for HTML audio and video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats).

Comment: updated my question, did you mean something like that?

Comment: No. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyRv0-oPfKE&html5=1` is the URL to an HTML document.

Comment: @Cetico The URL to a YouTube video can also be resolved from the page link: replace `/watch?v=VIDEO_HASH` with `/v/VIDEO_HASH`. Please read the information linked above for an understanding of what you are doing right or wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry but i failed, I tried replacing v=VIDEO_HASH, I read the answer. I understand that the video src input is asking for an mp4 file instead of a HTML page. So the only way to do it is through some shady mp4link API?

Comment: @Cetico If you really want to go your own way, instead of using the YouTube iframe-option: Yes