# How to load YouTube live video streaming in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, youtube, video-streaming

I need some doubt about youtube live video streaming. how to load that youtube live video stream inside of unity any possible. because unity default video player does not support youtube URL that only any other player for youtube URL supporting are not plz replay soon.

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please explain what you tried...add some code, show examples and explain the problem. This is not a code request forum. Check this link for learn how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asset store has plugins for youtube videos:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/?stay#!/search/page=1/sortby=relevance/query=youtube

i'm pretty sure unity video player plays youtube videos also, if you pass it the actual mp4 youtube video url. (you need to extract it with those plugins, use some website api to extract it, or make your own)

Comment: Thank you for your replay. but unity default video player did not play youtube URL. how to extract website API.

Comment: @Abbasj use one of those asset store plugins, or search for how to get youtube mp4, for example using php on a server https://stackoverflow.com/a/49687760/5452781 , can find other examples for c#, java etc..