How to send a video to a user via a link from Youtube
Is there any API to which, if you give a link to the video, it will return a link like "https://... .mp4", exactly the same with audio and with a profile photo. I want to write such a bot.
I tried it through pytube, but it downloads both video and audio to my PC.I'd like to get just a link to it to pass the bot

This is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566835/how-to-get-the-mp4-url-for-youtube-videos-using-youtube-v3-api

pytube has a url attribute per stream, you just need to pick the ones you are interested in (resolution, file format, ...)
from pytube import YouTube

link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wEe7SJAjbU'
yt = YouTube(link)
allStreams = yt.streams

for item in allStreams:
    print(item)
    print(item.url)
    print("")

Out:
<Stream: itag="18" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.42001E" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">
https://rr2---sn-4g5ednsy.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1712592589&ei=bcITZu3gA8aa1gL9ir6ICQ&ip=45.14.124.241&id=o-AJ1j3RNqxRyQ9QvbSWSomQiiZaey6TUh7ljJZW075ZUf&itag=18&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&xpc=EgVo2aDSNQ%3D%3D&mh=v2&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-4g5ednsy%2Csn-4g5lzne6&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=22&initcwndbps=1593750&bui=AaUN6a2J_acDpE1lQam7uoxFWcozef0rlmNQI_8KbouueOacKtBTfUCMifrEgCq55dp5I_WQAb_7GRPK&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=9312036&ratebypass=yes&dur=214.831&lmt=1711476278565194&mt=1712570685&fvip=4&fexp=51141541&c=ANDROID_EMBEDDED_PLAYER&txp=6309224&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cxpc%2Cbui%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJfQdSswRAIgHsA7kyZqVVHsnnnSirqhOogbeu_3gunfhSKMZi7ZLM0CIFw_7iwhNLLMoaHP5ovEKN8yQIcblXE4kT_vXYaRq0PK&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALClDIEwRQIhAJE4rAXhuJSUPN-9XyIK1Doz7zIUvlg0qmQazIrbF6eDAiB3QknEyrH-BADLhVHwVpcG7OM3x1Dl5bRZWanKSqK-yw%3D%3D

<Stream: itag="22" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.64001F" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">
https://rr2---sn-4g5ednsy.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1712592589&ei=bcITZu3gA8aa1gL9ir6ICQ&ip=45.14.124.241&id=o-AJ1j3RNqxRyQ9QvbSWSomQiiZaey6TUh7ljJZW075ZUf&itag=22&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&xpc=EgVo2aDSNQ%3D%3D&mh=v2&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-4g5ednsy%2Csn-4g5lzne6&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=22&initcwndbps=1593750&bui=AaUN6a2J_acDpE1lQam7uoxFWcozef0rlmNQI_8KbouueOacKtBTfUCMifrEgCq55dp5I_WQAb_7GRPK&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&cnr=14&ratebypass=yes&dur=214.831&lmt=1711476291542981&mt=1712570685&fvip=4&fexp=51141541&c=ANDROID_EMBEDDED_PLAYER&txp=6308224&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cxpc%2Cbui%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Ccnr%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJfQdSswRgIhAPuEhb7p9XdfTEGPddgrfuKH8_Xqr0I2ANYVW-n5bDU5AiEAsvXSZdsTAkEyYN2A109MU1g9MzaazmRrVgtB-X_igJA%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALClDIEwRQIhAJE4rAXhuJSUPN-9XyIK1Doz7zIUvlg0qmQazIrbF6eDAiB3QknEyrH-BADLhVHwVpcG7OM3x1Dl5bRZWanKSqK-yw%3D%3D

<Stream: itag="249" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="50kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">
https://rr2---sn-4g5ednsy.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1712592589&ei=bcITZu3gA8aa1gL9ir6ICQ&ip=45.14.124.241&id=o-AJ1j3RNqxRyQ9QvbSWSomQiiZaey6TUh7ljJZW075ZUf&itag=249&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&xpc=EgVo2aDSNQ%3D%3D&mh=v2&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-4g5ednsy%2Csn-4g5lzne6&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=22&initcwndbps=1593750&bui=AaUN6a0aYf_5VN0nMTTcCN9ZK53JfvJedkleFavpdJ07bgm1B2VWiGAC9dXSn5j_n4Qm5mbRhPXQaG3B&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=1405336&dur=214.801&lmt=1711476298166256&mt=1712570685&fvip=4&keepalive=yes&fexp=51141541&c=ANDROID_EMBEDDED_PLAYER&txp=6308224&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cxpc%2Cbui%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJfQdSswRAIgIjXV0XuL1PFYfgHOJfhmtXzLw_uW5r5e4gqDnZBKOr0CIGAGADvYhvndaQGctkS-JxLbqNUchEWPLT3nXLE4PP5Z&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALClDIEwRQIhAJE4rAXhuJSUPN-9XyIK1Doz7zIUvlg0qmQazIrbF6eDAiB3QknEyrH-BADLhVHwVpcG7OM3x1Dl5bRZWanKSqK-yw%3D%3D
...



Is there any API to which, if you give a link to the video, it will return a link

as far as I can understand this API seems to do exactly that
If you prefer to create your own I think you can find some hint
on this other stack overflow answer from ~7 months ago
(it works using an external tool called "yt-dlp")
